# Boost.Python polymorhpism. Down casting issue

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have a list of base classes in C++, I want to access them in Python as a list of their derived most classes.

Is there a build in means to cater for this in Boost.Python?

I've made an example the problem I ma facing:

```
// ------------------------------- Code ----------------------------------//
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
namespace boost { template<class T> T* get_pointer(std::shared_ptr<T>& p){ return p.get(); }}

struct Vehicle{ virtual ~Vehicle(){} friend bool operator==(const Vehicle& lhs, const Vehicle& rhs) { return true; }};
struct Boat: public Vehicle{ 
    virtual ~Boat(){} 
    friend bool operator==(const Boat& lhs, const Boat& rhs) { return true; }
    char const* testBoatSpecificMethod() { return "Floating."; }    
};
struct Truck: public Vehicle{ 
    virtual ~Truck(){} 
    friend bool operator==(const Truck& lhs, const Truck& rhs) { return true; }
    char const* testTruckSpecificMethod() { return "Trucking."; }
};

class Garage
{
public:
    Garage() {};
    ~Garage() {};
    char const* test() {  std::string temp = "Vehicle List Size: " + std::to_string(m_VehicleList.size()); return temp.c_str(); }
    friend bool operator==(const Garage& lhs, const Garage& rhs) { return true; }
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>>& vehicleList() { return m_VehicleList; }
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>> m_VehicleList;
};

#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp> 
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(garage_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<Garage>("Garage")
        .def("test", &Garage::test)
        .def("vehicleList", &Garage::vehicleList, return_internal_reference<1>());
    class_<Vehicle,std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>>("Vehicle");
    class_<Boat,std::shared_ptr<Boat>,bases<Vehicle>>("Boat")
        .def("testBoatSpecificMethod", &Boat::testBoatSpecificMethod);
    class_<Truck,std::shared_ptr<Truck>,bases<Vehicle>>("Truck")
        .def("testTruckSpecificMethod", &Truck::testTruckSpecificMethod);   

    implicitly_convertible<std::shared_ptr<Boat>,std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>>();
    implicitly_convertible<std::shared_ptr<Truck>,std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>>();
    class_<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>> >("stl_vector_Vehicle")
       .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>> >());
}

// --------------------------- Test Script -------------------------------//
import garage_ext
g = garage_ext.Garage()
l = g.vehicleList()
l.append(garage_ext.Boat())
print "Expecting a Boat object:"
print str(l[0])
print g.vehicleList()[0].testBoatSpecificMethod()
garage_ext.f2("Done.")
```

// ------------------------------ Output ---------------------------------//

Expecting a Boat object

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_garage.py", line 7, in 
    print g.vehicleList()[0].testBoatSpecificMethod()
AttributeError: 'Vehicle' object has no attribute 'testBoatSpecificMethod'

'Vehicle' object has no attribute 'testBoatSpecificMethod'
Here I want Vehicle to be a Boat object.

If there is not a build-in or recommended/known Boost.Python means to handle this problem,
I'll try wrapping the list (Lots of wrapping to be done then in my library.) with a get accessor returning a boost::python::list, storing the derived most types in the python list object. Getting the derived most type possibly by calling overriden 'getAsDerivedClass' method. 
I would like to avoid this. I dislike having to add python usage specific methods to the library, for our design and vision values / reasons. Another concern is that this way will introduce a lot of extramaintenance work.

**EDIT:**
What I want works when I am using raw pointers instead of smart pointers.
For what I feel are obvious reasons,I do not want to use raw pointers in place of smart pointers.
This does give me a relieve in that knowing what I want this concept isn't so far-fetched as I started to fear. (I am struggling still to make it work with smart pointers. The python object asks for a converter, too much work to write one by hand.)

Comment: You are doing inheritance wrong: you can't store a vector<Vehicle> and expect it to have runtime polymorphism.  This is just general C++, you need to store e.g. vector<unique_ptr<Vehicle>> or shared_ptr or so.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thank you John, I fixed the code. I mistakenly forgot to make the list a list of shared pointers. You can notice by the Boost.Python conversion code that vector<shared_ptr<Vehicle>> was the intention.
The issue is still there, unfortunately not just general C++ as you can make out from my description.

Comment: Right so now the problem seems to be that the `boatSpecificMethod` etc. are not present as `virtual` methods in your base class.  They need to be, I think...or your vector needs to hold boost::python::objects or something else which will make life trickier.

Comment: Yeah, this is where I am at now. That's why I mentioned wrapping the list using a boost::python::list storing the derived most types. This is unwanted for reasons mentioned and I am trying to find out if there is not a built-in mechanism in Boost.Python for this.

Comment: Note, I called in BoatSpecificMethod to demonstrate that I want to use methods specific to the derived class only, not existing as virtual in the base.

Comment: *I called IT BoatSpecificMethod, not IN  BoatSpecificMethod

Comment: If you want type erasure but don't want to use boost::python::list, you could try boost::variant I guess?  At the end of the day what you're going for here is fundamentally a bit problematic.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thank you for your input. Once I use raw pointers instead of smart pointers, it works. See my edit. This gives me hope that may not be fundamentally a bit problematic.

Comment: You could try `class_<Boat,std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>`...sort of a lark I will admit.

Comment: @JohnZwinck You got me excited there for a while :) . I get an error from the pointer_holder.hpp file: invalid conversion from ‘Vehicle*’ to ‘Boat*’. Adding implicit conversion from Vehicle* to Boat* doesn't help either. I can see this approach introducing potential issues, but as you said, sort of a lark.